# What does exec() do in this program? Does it stop running?

Tags: c, operating-system, system-calls

```
int main(void){
char *argv[3] = {"Command-line","-1", NULL};
int i;
int pid = fork();
if(pid == 0){
   for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
      execvp("ls", argv);
      fork();
      printf("%d\n",i);
    }
    printf("One\n");
  }
printf("Two\n");
return 0;
}
```

What does execvp do in this program? Does the child process continue to run after this execvp call or does it stop there and only the parent process continues?

Another question is, do all the exec calls do the same thing but only with different arguments?

Comment: Unless `execvp` fails, it does not return.

Comment: `fork` after `execvp` does not make sense because `execvp` does not return if it succeeds.

Comment: It does not "stop running".  The child becomes an instance of `ls` which runs to completion and exits.

Comment: The fork after execvp doesn't make sense but it's an exam question as a test.
So, once execvp is finished, the process that executes it doesn't execute the lines below it?
If this is true, is this the same for all exec calls?

Comment: Much of this code doesn't make sense.  The loop is useless, and the code after `execvp` serves no purpose.  Any code after `execvp` should do something like print an error message indicating that the call failed.

Comment: As for "do all the exec calls do the same thing" suggest you read the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) for the details and post a more specific question about what you specifically don't understand after reading that

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly handles errors

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    char *args[] = { "ls", NULL };
    int pid = fork();
    switch(pid)
    {
        case 0:
            execvp("ls", args);
            perror( "execvp failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            break;
            
        case -1:
            perror( "fork failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            break;
            
        default:
            waitpid( pid, NULL, 0 );
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

a partial listing of the output (when no errors occur) is:

```
...
untitled
untitled1.c
untitled1.o
untitled2
untitled2.c
untitled2.o
untitled.c
untitled.c~
untitled.html
untitled.mak
untitled.o
untitled.s
untitled.txt
...
```